# WCF service contracts designs

Tags: c#, wcf

In a business application, ideas are dynamics and daily exponential growth.
and there isn't such a service contract fit all requiremens neither do with many contracts .
let says we ended up 100 000 of contracts which they are ended up 100 000 end points.

is there anyone come accross these kinds of problem which they are limited by WCF?
or WCF isn't for an real business application but rather a integration to a business application and exposed a fraction of data exchange?

Could someone kindly show some thoughts?

Regards

Thanks Chris,

I found it is hard to believe as well , 100K tables are fictious but nearly 2000 tables are normal.

let say an application with 100K tables, for each service contract, it needs to receive or return a serializable object which it is a table entity in this case.
 that means 100K tables would end up 100K service contracts of less and each has some basic implementation such as findby primary key, query methods which returns some sort of array or list and a write method for update/insert.

on top of a table, we would have many business logic method . eg SalesOrderTable would also have methods such as create from qoute, available to promise, total, discount, tax...etc

how would you have a service contract which can provide such information to client side without many contract interfaces/end points?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to believe you could end up with hundred of thousands of contracts/end points unless you're doing something very wrong/odd... perhaps you could provide an example.

Comment: If you're ending up with 100k endpoints, you're not thinking about the implementation very well. You're also not considering service versioning or deprecating old/unused services. Maybe after it's all said and done you've iterated over 100k endpoints (Still hard to believe) but you shouldn't have that many actual endpoints.

Comment: It'll be fine.  Service granularity usually defines how many services you have, and I've seen huge applications with far less than 100 service and data contracts, even with fine grained services.

Comment: I don't have a sample application, I'm still in a thinking process and I can not sure how a limited number of service contracts with a recommended 12 operations per contract fit together.

Comment: So, you have 2K tables, for each table you're planning on exposing CRUD services?  Do your clients *really* need that level of access?  Isn't it possible to map at least some of the tables to `DataContract`'s, rather than `ServiceContract`'s?  Then expose higher level functionality to the clients?  That should significantly reduce the number of services/operations required.

Comment: I don't have a sample application, I'm still in a thinking process and I can not sure how a limited number of service contracts with a recommended 12 operations per contract fit together. and how do we consider to have a new functionalities/service contract while application in production, Please take a look at sample stock trade application .NET StockTrader Sample Application, such a small application with a very few tables and it does make very complex in term of structure with many service contracts and end points. I'm really unsure how others did it. Could some one give some light.

Comment: Thank forsvarir, How do we manipulate data without exposing CRUD to service contract? I'm not understanding - could you kindly explain further.

Comment: Services generally provide a layer of abstraction over much more fine-grained operations. For example, if you had a Transactions table, an Orders table and Customers table, it would be preferable to have a service with a PlaceOrder method that takes pertinent pieces of information and interacts with those pieces for the caller according to the required business logic instead of handing the caller three table objects and say "Deal with it yourself".

Comment: Please correct me if I'm taking it wrong here, According to your answers- Service contracts are for a "fine-gained operations", therefore making WCF for core enterprise application server is a big NO, WCF for an additional function to service a specifice need is a YES.

Comment: I wonder if this should be moved over to programmers? Or chat...

Comment: My appologies, If I have posed this message to a wrong place. Please guide us to a right direction. I've very keen to know the solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit abstract, so may be better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com , however I think there are still some points that would need to be cleared up before it can be really answered.

It’s unclear what you mean by this ‘WCF isn't for an real business application but rather a integration to a business application’.  When combined with some of the comments you’ve added, it reads a bit like you’re suggesting that you have 1:1 mapping between your services + either your database tables, or your classes.  It’s unclear if the business logic methods, such as ‘create from quote’ would sit behind a service interface (so the business logic is in the service), or sit in front of the service (i.e. the business logic is in the client).

You also seem to be worrying about what at the moment appears to be a spurious requirement (100k tables/services), since at the moment you appear to be dealing with 2k tables...  It’s also unclear where some of your ideas come from, such as the 12 recommended operations per contract (ITradeService in the example you’ve indicated has 19 operations).

Would WCF be able to scale up to 100k services?  Yes, however you are going to have similar problems to those that you would encounter if you were to try to model a system with 100k classes, or 100k tables.  You are going to want to partition the data/logic in an appropriate manner so that they can handle the overhead / requirements and so that they are relatively intuitive to use.  This would probably mean that you would want to distribute the services across many servers.

However, as I’ve said in the comments, this would seem like a very odd situation for you to be in.  If you need to model 100k services, then either you’re trying to expose too much through the services, or you have an exceptionally large domain that you are trying to model.

Generally, I would expect services to be at a higher level of abstraction than the database model. As an example, let’s take a typical customer model... the database may consist of tables like:

- Customer – Core customer details, keyed by id
- Address – Represents a postal address
- Customer Address – Maps customer to address, for a given period of time
- Phone Number – Represents a phone number
- Customer Phone Number – Maps a customer to a phone number, for a given period of time, includes type (mobile, home etc)
- Etc....

You could expose each of the tables as a CRUD operation from a service, but this seems like a bad idea.   The logic to ‘register a customer’ may then sit at the client.  They would have to create all of the table entries in the correct order to maintain database integrity.  An alternative would be to have a ‘Customer’ service that contained an operation ‘RegisterCustomer’, which took in a `DataContract` ‘NewCustomerData’, which included basic customer details, address details, phone number details etc... Only one operation is required rather than many to achieve the same results and the client interaction is easier and less error prone.

Not a complete answer, but perhaps something to start with... You may also want to take a look at [Principles of Service Design: Service Patterns and Anti-Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954638.aspx).  Whilst it’s a bit old, it does cover some useful topics.  I'd suggest that at this point, you may need to think a bit more about what it is you're trying to achieve and how you see your model looking before perhaps coming back with more specific questions.

Comment: I'm really appreciate your thoughts on this. In the book "Programming WCF services" at pg 827 point no 6, it said "Do not have more than 20 members per serice contract. Twelve is probably the practical limit". I'm still very confuse if we don't have CRUD operations from WCF service, even we introduced a middle data type "NewCustomerData" as you suggested it is only 4/5 times less for CRUD. given 2000, tables we'll labor programming for 500 contracts approx. beside there'd be many intelligent business logics apply to these tables. I hope there is a better way and it seems very labor intensive.

Comment: It's going to be hard to give you advice, because your problem is very abstract.  So obvious questions include: What is it you're trying to achieve by using web services?  Why do you feel you need to expose *all* of the tables?  What are the clients requirements?  If you feel that there's too much work involved, what are the alternatives that are less work, but achieve the same goal?  Service design should be driven by the behaviour/functionality that you want to make available to your clients, not by what you *can* make available.

Comment: I developed an App many years ago, I would like to rewrite it, I'm thinking about C# and WCF...etc. to get this a little more specific, I would immagine a 3 layers application, Database layer, Application Server layer and Client UI layer. Client UI would connect to AppServer and it should not have any direct connection to DB. AppServer would handle ALL CLIENTS REQUESTS. At the moment, I'm thinking about using WCF in AppServer to handle all requests such as CRUD, validations, business rules and new business rules(on the fly) which i have no idea how to do this yet. continue in the nx coments..

Comment: as an appServer provides service to client,It would provide all kind of service without limitation of what are defined.As we can see WCF send or receive data with a known data type or predefined contract interfaces,this means every time we expand database or expand application logic,we would have to add new contract and new service.As basic as CRUD ops,our AppServer would be amended/added everytime we add a new table to support client UI -As someone said CRUD is bad via WCF,but I don't know whereelse would this be handled if it isn't in AppServer,introducing mid objs are just more implication